# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export" while importing Office ui/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I follow the guide at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric

I try to import like the guide shows:

```
import  {TextField}  from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
```

My project compiles without errors but when I try to run it, it crashes and this gets logged out:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

How come?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to include `office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';`
just import `import {TextField} from 'office-ui-fabric-react';`

Check this reference link [https://codesandbox.io/embed/y0o9o2815v]